# Filling an array inside multiple nested foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Novice programmer here. I'm having the following problem: I am using multiple nested foreach(es?),  and inside the last foreach I echo my variable, $item->getLabel(). What appears is correct but I'm getting many duplicate results, which is also correct but unwanted.

Then I found out I could put the variable each time inside an array, then hopefully I could use array_unique on it. Thing is, how do I accomplish that? I tried the following inside the last foreach:

```
$input = array($item->getLabel());
```

but I know it is wrong, as it obviously overwrites the array with just the last item with each passing of the foreach loop.

The following code outside all foreaches,

```
echo ++$count . $input[0] . "<br>";
```

verifies that, as it only echoes the last item, and of course $input[1] and so forth are empty.

What do I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change it to below in your foreach,

```
$input[] = $item->getLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `$input` as a variable instead as an array.